# Scrap de precios devuelve un precio que no se ve en pantalla

Tags: html, r, scraping, rvest

Estoy intentando scrapear precios de una pagina donde se dan tres situaciones:

- Productos con descuento (se ven 2 precios en la página) https://www.carrefour.com.ar/cebolla-x-kg/p
- Productos que tienen descuento en la segunda unidad o con tarjetas especificas(se ven 2
  precios) https://www.carrefour.com.ar/aceite-de-girasol-carrefour-alto-omega-pet-900-cc-699030-699030/p
- Productos sin ningún descuento (un solo precio) https://www.carrefour.com.ar/aceite-de-girasol-pureza-1500-cc/p

El segundo y el tercer caso los puedo captar con price_1 y price_2, el problema esta en los productos con descuento. Cuando scrapeo ese caso, me devuelve el precio con descuento y un segundo precio distinto al publicado en la página. (por ejemplo en el caso del link, el precio de lista es $227, con descuento $169 pero cuando corro el scrap me devuelve $279). Alguna idea de que puede ser?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(readxl)
library(writexl)
library(curl)
library(httr)
library(pbapply)

scraping_unidad <- function(entrada){
  tryCatch(
    error = function(e){
      mensaje = "Excepcion"
    },
    {main_page <-tryCatch(read_html(entrada), error=function(e) NA)
    
    price_1 <- tryCatch(main_page %>%html_nodes(".lyracons-carrefourarg-product-price-1-x-currencyInteger") %>% html_text(),error=function(e) NA)
    
    price_2 <- tryCatch(main_page %>% html_nodes(".strike") %>% html_nodes(".lyracons-carrefourarg-product-price-1-x-currencyInteger") %>% html_text(),error=function(e) NA)
```

Comment: Tu pregunta ahora mismo ya no es replicable. Los precios que indicas con descuento me salen ambos con un único valor en pantalla. Trata de [edit] e incluir en la pregunta la estructura que sale en cada caso (el fragmento relevante, al menos) para que la pregunta pueda revisarse ahora mismo y en el futuro.

Comment: Buscando alguno con oferta, que desde Colombia sale [este](https://www.carrefour.com.ar/aceite-de-girasol-carrefour-alto-omega-pet-900-cc-699030-699030/p), se puede comentar que a) yo usaría los identificadores `.lyracons-carrefourarg-product-price-1-x-listPrice` y `.lyracons-carrefourarg-product-price-1-x-sellingPriceValue` para identificar el precio de lista y el precio de venta; b) tienes que ver el HTML que obtienes en cada caso y ver si el correr un script que no anda aceptando cookies y tiene un agente particular, afecta lo que la página te ofrece.

Comment: Es muy común que muestren precios diferentes dependiendo de quién los ve y cómo los ve...

Comment: A mi me sale el precio especificado.

Comment: Si, efectivamente te muestra otro precio, se puede verificar descargando el HTML: `download.file("https://www.carrefour.com.ar/cebolla-x-kg/p", destfile = "scrapedpage.html", quiet=TRUE)`. el problema es `rvest` que no sirve mucho con páginas dinámicas como esta. Deberías intentar usar `RSelenium`

Comment: Mi hipótesis es que hay una página default con el precio de 279$ para la cebolla (que cara está la cebolla) pero en función de vaya a saber que cosas, mediante javascript/ajax se redibuja en tu browser y se modifican los precios., el problema es que `rvest` solo puede leer la "primer pagina" y no la final, para está última es que necesitas `rselenium`